# How to set custom validation message in Laravel 5.2 for multi language?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My website has three language ‍['English', 'Persian', 'Arabic'].

For example:

In `Request`:

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'mobile' => 'required|max:11|min:11',
        'register_id' => 'required|max:7|min:7'
    ];
}
```

I want After selecting the language by the user, An error message is displayed in the selected language.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for localization? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Comment: @craig_h Thank you so much, please insert answer in stack overflow , I would like to...

Comment: @craig_h Thank you, I can accept after 2 min :-) but how to change language in Laravel?

Comment: @craig_h i find `config/app.php`, I copy the folder en then rename to `fa`, but after change message, No unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use different languages in your `laravel` app then you can use the built in localization:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

**EDIT:**

For your purposes, I would approach it like this.

First, create your language folders in `resources/lang`, for example, for you Arabic messages you would place a `messages.php` in `resource/lang/ar`

I'm not sure how you are storing a users language, so I'll assume it's stored in the session as `lang`.

Now you can create middleware to check the users chosen language and set the locale:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // set language from session
    \App::setLocale(session('lang'));
    return $next($request);
}
```

Now register that as global middleware in: `app\Kernal.php`

Now your `app` should automatically set the locale before each request based on the 'lang' value in the session. Make sure you have `fallback_locale` set so your app knows what to do if your user doesn't have a locale set.